How to click on each of the apartments on Airbnb using selenium
I am making a scraper for Airbnb. The scraper should enter one apartment, take a screenshot, go back, enter the second apartment, take screenshot, etc.
The scraper currently clicks on the first apartment, takes screenshot, comes back and then again enters the first apartment instead of the next one. The HTML that I am currently clicking on under the variable elements is the following:
<a aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="rfexzly atm_9s_1ulexfb atm_7l_1j28jx2 atm_e2_1osqo2v dir dir-ltr" href="/rooms/9477823?category_tag=Tag%3A8678&amp;enable_m3_private_room=true&amp;photo_id=127120043&amp;check_in=2024-05-08&amp;check_out=2024-05-22&amp;source_impression_id=p3_1714848134_RZNZRm8eG%2FJ26pww&amp;previous_page_section_name=1000&amp;federated_search_id=efebfc50-8682-44ac-acee-e5d374cb3da4" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" target="listing_9477823"><div class="cjv59qb atm_mk_h2mmj6 atm_vy_1osqo2v atm_e2_1osqo2v dir dir-ltr"><div class="d1l1iq7v atm_9s_1o8liyq atm_vh_yfq0k3 atm_e2_88yjaz atm_vy_1r2rij0 atm_j6_t94yts bmwtyu7 atm_2m_1qred53 atm_2s_mgnkw2 dir dir-ltr" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="--dls-liteimage-height: 100%; --dls-liteimage-width: 100%; --dls-liteimage-background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,null'); --dls-liteimage-background-size: cover;"><picture class=" dir dir-ltr"><source srcset="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/73075622-b70f-426e-bf7e-f1d54885e049.jpg?im_w=720 1x" media="(min-width: 0px)"><img class="itu7ddv atm_e2_idpfg4 atm_vy_idpfg4 atm_mk_stnw88 atm_e2_1osqo2v__1lzdix4 atm_vy_1osqo2v__1lzdix4 i1cqnm0r atm_jp_pyzg9w atm_jr_nyqth1 i1de1kle atm_vh_yfq0k3 dir dir-ltr" aria-hidden="true" elementtiming="LCP-target" fetchpriority="high" loading="eager" src="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/73075622-b70f-426e-bf7e-f1d54885e049.jpg?im_w=720" data-original-uri="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/73075622-b70f-426e-bf7e-f1d54885e049.jpg?im_w=720" style="--dls-liteimage-object-fit: cover;"></picture><div class="rsb5yse atm_9s_1o8liyq atm_vh_yfq0k3 atm_e2_1osqo2v atm_vy_1osqo2v atm_9s_glywfm__1lzdix4 bmwtyu7 atm_2m_1qred53 atm_2s_mgnkw2 dqqltwe atm_2g_1isa5lx atm_2w_k6d6ah dir dir-ltr" style="--dls-liteimage-background-size: cover; --dls-liteimage-background-image: url(https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/73075622-b70f-426e-bf7e-f1d54885e049.jpg?im_w=720);"></div></div></div></a>

The part that needs fixing is this part. What part of the HTML elements should I focus on when clicking it so it clicks all of the elements?
#...rest of the code

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-hidden='true'][tabindex='-1'][class*='dir'][href*='/rooms/']")

for element in elements:
    element.click()

#...rest of the code

Here is the full code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/San-Francisco--California--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-06-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-09-01&price_filter_input_type=0&channel=EXPLORE&query=San%20Francisco%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States&place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2024-05-08&checkout=2024-05-22&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(4)

try:
    accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-application"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button')
    accept_cookies.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No 'Accept cookies' found.")

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-hidden='true'][tabindex='-1'][class*='dir'][href*='/rooms/']")

for element in elements:
    element.click()

    # Switch to the newly opened tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    time.sleep(4)

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

    try:
        close_pop_up = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           '/html/body/div[9]/div/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')
        close_pop_up.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No pop up element found.")

    apartment_name = soup.find('h1', class_='hpipapi').getText()

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, 100);")

    driver.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{apartment_name.replace(" ", "_")}.png')

    # Close the current tab
    driver.close()

    # Switch back to the main tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

driver.quit()


The issue with your code is that following line of code is actually selecting elements for images of a single apartment that's why its keep clicking on same place.
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-hidden='true'][tabindex='-1'][class*='dir'][href*='/rooms/']")

**Here is Complete working Code **
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/San-Francisco--California--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2024-06-01&monthly_length=3&monthly_end_date=2024-09-01&price_filter_input_type=0&channel=EXPLORE&query=San%20Francisco%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States&place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&date_picker_type=calendar&checkin=2024-05-08&checkout=2024-05-22&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)

try:
    accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-application"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/section/div[2]/div[2]/button')
    accept_cookies.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No 'Accept cookies' found.")

#fix start from here -->
# This is unique element for every apartment that contains URL of aparment details
allApartments = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//meta[@itemprop='url']")
totalNumbreOfApartments = len(allApartments)
print("There are total ", totalNumbreOfApartments, "found on this page")

apartmentLinks = []
for apartment in allApartments:
    apartmentUrl = apartment.get_attribute('content')
#Be aware the link is not starting with https://, so we need to add it
    apartmentUrl = "https://" + apartmentUrl 
    apartmentLinks.append(apartmentUrl)
    apartmentUrl = ""

for link in apartmentLinks:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(link)  # Fix Ends here
    time.sleep(4)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

    try:
        close_pop_up = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           '/html/body/div[9]/div/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')
        close_pop_up.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No pop up element found.")

    apartment_name = soup.find('h1', class_='hpipapi').getText()

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, 100);")
    driver.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{apartment_name.replace(" ", "_")}.png')

    # Close the current tab
    driver.close()

    # Switch back to the main tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

driver.quit()

